# Laravel 5.5: laravel.log could not be opened: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a simple Laravel command line on my Elastic Beanstalk instance: `php artisan queue:work`

But I keep getting the following error:

> In StreamHandler.php line 107:
>
> The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log" could
>   not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I've tried every solution I can find on SO (except the `chmod -R 777` advice that seems to trail this question everywhere).

I've tried deleting the existing `laravel.log` and then using `touch` to create a new one, and then making sure `webapp` is the owner.

I've also tried:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/app/current/storage/
sudo chown -R webapp /var/app/current/storage/
```

When I list the logs directory, everything looks as I think it should:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 webapp webapp     0 Apr  4 14:38 laravel.log
```

The storage directory also looks fine:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 webapp webapp   4096 Apr  3 19:33 storage
```

But I'm still getting the above error! Can anyone *explain why* (not just give a solution).

Thank you

Comment: What user is your worker running as?

Comment: try running `sudo -u webapp php artisan queue:work`

Comment: @apokryfos Ah. That makes sense. I'm a little out of my comfort zone with server side. Strangely it appears to work without error... but it's not actually processing the queue either. Ugh

Comment: Whether or not the queue gets processed really depends of a lot of reasons. For example I can never get the queue worker to process the default queue, I always have to explicitly specify which queue it needs to process.

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage/
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current/storage/

Comment: @FaridulKhan Never do that. https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/never-use-777-to-solve-a-permission-issue/1545

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the simple answer is that I was running the command as `ec2-user`. As a solution, I could either:

1. Change the ownership of laravel.log to `ec2-user`
2. Run the command as the owner (eg. `sudo -u webapp php artisan queue:work`)
3. Switch to root with `sudo su` to see how it would be run during deployment (ie. as `root`)

Nothing was especially wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you log into an EBS instance via ssh, you're logged in as `ec2-user`.

I don't believe the `ec2-user` is part of the `webapp` group which is actually executing PHP & apache/nginx.

Try adding your `ec2-user` to the webapp group by creating an ebextension in the root of your Laravel project under `.ebextensions/ec2user.config`

```
users:
  ec2-user:
    groups:
      - webapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Prove this is the problem by turning off selinux with the command

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

This should allow writing, but you've turned off added security server-wide. That's bad. Turn SELinux back

```
sudo setenforce 1
```

Then finally use SELinux to allow writing of the file by using this command

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
```

And you're off!